# Evenly Spaced Integer Topology is Metrizable

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

[Furstenberg's proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furstenberg%27s_proof_of_the_infinitude_of_primes) uses an evenly spaced integer topology on $\mathbb Z$ which declares that a basis of open sets as those of the form $a + b \mathbb Z$ (i.e. arithmetic progressions). I'm interested in whether this space is metrizable.

[Pi-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000050/properties/P000053) claims that is, but I can't understand what's written. It says

> The topology on $X$ is generated by the metric $d(n,m) = \frac{1}{2^k}$ where $k$ is the largest number such that $p^k \mid |n-m|$ (and $d(n,n) = 0$).
>
> Note that with this metric, $B(n,\frac{1}{2^{-k}}) = \{m: p^l | |n-m|\}$ for some $l > k = \bigcup_{l > k} \{n+ap^l : a \in X\} = U_{k+1}(n)$.

I can't understand what this is saying. Presumably $p$ is a *fixed* prime (otherwise $\frac{1}{8} = d(0,81)+d(81,97) < d(0,97)=1$, for example). But then I don't see how $q\mathbb Z$ can possibly contain any neighborhood of zero (where $q \ne p$ is also prime), since any neighborhood of zero seems to necessarily contain a power of $p$.

Am I misunderstanding something? Thanks.

Comment: It *is* true that the topology is metrizable; [this blog post](https://teratologicmuseum.wordpress.com/2009/05/05/a-metric-for-the-evenly-spaced-integer-topology/) gives a construction.

Comment: And because it is countable and has no isolated points, it is homeomorphic to the rationals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest argument is that $X$ is regular, Hausdorff, and second countable and therefore metrizable by the Uryson metrization theorem.

- It’s second countable, since the base used to define it is countable.
- Each of the basic open sets $a+b\Bbb Z$ is clopen, so it’s regular (indeed, completely regular): if $n\notin a+b\Bbb Z$, then $n+b\Bbb Z$ is an open nbhd of $n$ disjoint from $a+b\Bbb Z$.
- If $m\ne n$, let $b=|m-n|+1$; then $m+b\Bbb Z$ and $n+b\Bbb Z$ are disjoint open nbhds of $m$ and $n$, so $X$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: In this space, is there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for any clopen subset $U$ of $X$  the set $\beta_\epsilon (x)\subset U$ for any $x\in U$?

Comment: @M.A.: Since no metric has been specified, your question really doesn’t make sense. However, it turns out that $X$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q$, and no metric on $\Bbb Q$ has that property, so no metric on $X$ has it, either. In fact every point has a local base of clopen sets, so in any compatible metric there are clopen sets of arbitrarily small diameter.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. In fact, every connected and also every compact disconnected metric spaces have this property. I am looking for an example of a non-compact disconnected metric space with this property. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @M.A.: That’s not quite right: te Cantor set is compact and not connected, and it does *not* have that property, for the same reason that the rationals do not have it: it has a base of clopen sets. It you just want the non-compact metric space not to be connected, it’s easy: start with a connected metric space $M$ with more than one point, like $\Bbb R$, and an infinite discrete space $D$, and let $X=D\times M$. If you want it to be totally disconnected, look at **Theorem** $\mathbf{2}$ of [this PDF](http://www.math.binghamton.edu/dennis/479.s11/zerodim-totdisc.pdf).