# Homeomorphism between evenly spaced integer topology and the rationals

Tags: general-topology, order-topology

The evenly spaced integer topology is countable, metrizable, and has no isolated points, and hence is homeomorphic to the rationals with the order topology. But what is an explicit construction for this homeomorphism?

Comment: I found this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232215/evenly-spaced-integer-topology-is-metrizable which might provide some clues.

Comment: The beauty of the theorem you quoted is that you actually don't care about the explicitness. There is a homeomorphism, and that's enough. Why would anyone want an explicit construction?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I am not the OP but I like this question. I think the motivation is that these are two fairly simple explicit metric spaces and the explicit construction might turn out to be quite simple/beautiful. Basically, just curiosity!

Comment: I don't think I need to justify the usefulness of constructive proofs in general, but at any rate the purpose of this question is to construct the homeomorphism explicitly.

Comment: @Asvin, the problem is, there are very many homeomorphisms and which one is beautiful, or natural etc.? None might be. It can be made explicit modulo enumerations (well-order everything in sight, as Mary-Ellen used to say) but why choose one way above the other? I'd welcome a nice and intuitive homeomorphism, but I don't see why one would exist in the first place.

Comment: @Asvin right, and particularly the thing I find interesting is that these spaces are homeomorphic but not order-isomorphic. The topology on the rationals shakes out of the order topology, so that the open sets have (roughly) countable dense order type. But the connected open sets in the evenly spaced integer topology look a lot different. Does it imply some sort of partial order on the integers? If p, q are rationals with p < q and f(...) is the homeomorphism from rationals to integers, what can be said about f(p) and f(q)? That sort of thing.